# Strongloop file upload - Invalid value for argument 'file' of type 'file'

Tags: node.js, file-upload, loopbackjs, strongloop

I've been struggling for a while with this ever since I upgraded to loopback `2.27` and component-storage `1.7`.

When I was using loopback 2.22, everything worked fine. Now every time I try to upload a file I get this:

```
Invalid value for argument 'file' of type 'file': [object Object]. Received type was converted to object.
```

What could be happening here?

Comment: So to be clear, the *exact* same code worked in 2.22? Can you run both side by side to compare?

Comment: It was the remote method argument's type, which changed from "file" to "object"

Comment: does anyone know what file type request expect?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. My remote method had a file argument of type "file". Had to change that to have type "object" and that was it.

Comment: Has anyone found why is this happens and how to use the type 'file'?

Comment: can you give more detail?